# ckeditor : forbidden You don't have permission to access /includes/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php on this server

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am new to ckeditor. I received the following error message

> Forbidden: You don't have permission to access includes/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php on this server. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I clicked on images and then upload and then choose file and then send it to server. I don't know how to correct this error. Please help

Comment: Did you check your folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use CKEditor with a user which has the necessary permissions to all folders and files involved. The user you are working with does not have access to at least a folder or the file in the path given.

Comment: I gave read write execute permission like 776 the folder ckfinder but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to open: ckeditor>ckfinder>config.php and in there you have function named: `CheckAuthentication() function:` In there you must have

```
function CheckAuthentication()       
        {                                    
           //WARNING : DO NOT simply...      
           ...                               
           return false;                     
        }
```

Remove this function CheckAuthentication()

I found a very good article where you can try and find a solution for your problem. Try it

https://www.drupal.org/node/728210

I hope it is useful!

Comment: actually  I am using session to return true here

Comment: Check it just in case. If it's not working I may suggest another thing. I just found pretty good article and updated my answer.

Comment: I removed it  and included
require_once '../../../../includes/filemanager.config.php'; after  $baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl); but still the same problem